# Logic to Transform data

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have an api that return me data in following format:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": 1567362600000,
        "KIDate": "2019-09-02",
        "KITools": [
            {
                "data": 1,
                "tool": "A"
            },
            {
                "data": 2,
                "tool": "B"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1567519839316,
        "KIDate": "2019-09-01",
        "KITools": [
            {
                "data": 2,
                "tool": "A"
            },
{
                "data": 1,
                "tool": "C"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1567519839317,
        "KIDate": "2019-08-31",
        "KITools": [
            {
                "data": 0,
                "tool": "C"
            }
        ]
    },
  ]
```

I want to transform this data to get the following arrays:

```js
Result 1 -  [“2019-09-02”,”2019-09-01”,”2019-08-31”]
Result 2 -  [ {name: ‘A’, data:[1, 2, 0] }, { name: 'B', data: [2, 0, 0] }, { name: 'C', data: [0, 1, 0]}]
```

Currently I am able to achieve this by using loops and per-defining variables with the tool name like following and looping the api data to push into this variable.

> var result2 = [{
>               name: 'A',
>               data: []
>           }, {
>               name: 'B',
>               data: []
>           }, {
>               name: 'C',
>               data: []
>           }];

But this is not the expected behavior, the tool names can change and I have to figure that out dynamically based on the data returned by the api.
What is the best way to achieve this without looping like crazy.

Comment: why is *looping like crazy* a bad thing?

Comment: I assume the _like crazy_ part is bad when we're trying to write _sane_ programs...

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce I never said its bad. See fighting a bear isn't bad, but I would choose to avoid it.

Comment: What do you mean by _the tool names can change_? The attribute _tool_ could be named differently? The values of _tool_ attribute could be different from _A_, _B_, or _C_?

Comment: @mgarcia yup exactly. It can be anything A,B,C....X,Y,Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method to get the result with array of dates and object of values for each tool.

```js
const data = [{"_id":1567362600000,"KIDate":"2019-09-02","KITools":[{"data":1,"tool":"A"},{"data":2,"tool":"B"}]},{"_id":1567519839316,"KIDate":"2019-09-01","KITools":[{"data":2,"tool":"A"},{"data":1,"tool":"C"}]},{"_id":1567519839317,"KIDate":"2019-08-31","KITools":[{"data":0,"tool":"C"}]}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {KIDate, KITools}, i) => {
  r.dates.push(KIDate);
  
  KITools.forEach(({data: dt, tool}) => {
    if(!r.values[tool]) r.values[tool] = Array(data.length).fill(0);
    r.values[tool][i] = dt
  })
  
  return r;
}, {dates: [], values: {}})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `forEach` with `Set` and `Map`

- Initialize accumulator as object with `dates` and `data` key, `dates` is a `Set` and data is `Map`
- For every element add the `KIDate` to dates key,
- Loop over `KITools`, check if that particular too exists in data `Map` if it exists update it's value by adding current values to id, if not set it's value as per current values

```js
let data = [{"_id": 1567362600000,"KIDate": "2019-09-02","KITools": [{"data": 1,"tool": "A"},{"data": 2,"tool": "B"}]},{"_id": 1567519839316,"KIDate": "2019-09-01","KITools": [{"data": 2,"tool": "A"},{"data": 1,"tool": "C"}]},{"_id": 1567519839317,"KIDate": "2019-08-31","KITools": [{"data": 0,"tool": "C"}]},]
  
let final = data.reduce((op,{KIDate,KITools})=>{
  op.dates.add(KIDate)
  KITools.forEach(({data,tool})=>{
    if(op.data.has(data)){
        op.data.get(data).data.push(tool)
    } else{
      op.data.set(data, {name: data, data:[tool]})
    }
  })
  return op
},{dates:new Set(),data: new Map()})

console.log([...final.dates.values()])
console.log([...final.data.values()])
```

Comment: Awesome Code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `result1` array can be obtained via a direct `.map()`. To build the `result2` array will require additional work - one approach would be to do so via [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as detailed below:

```js
const data=[{"_id":1567362600000,"KIDate":"2019-09-02","KITools":[{"data":1,"tool":"A"},{"data":2,"tool":"B"}]},{"_id":1567519839316,"KIDate":"2019-09-01","KITools":[{"data":2,"tool":"A"},{"data":1,"tool":"C"}]},{"_id":1567519839317,"KIDate":"2019-08-31","KITools":[{"data":0,"tool":"C"}]}];

const result1 = data.map(item => item.KIDate);
const result2 = data.reduce((result, item) => {

  item.KITools.forEach(kitool => {
    /* For current item, search for matching tool on name/tool fields */
    let foundTool = result.find(i => i.name === kitool.tool);
    if (foundTool) {
      /* Add data to data sub array if match found */
      foundTool.data.push(kitool.data);
    } else {
      /* Add new tool if no match found and init name and data array */
      result.push({
        name: kitool.tool,
        data: [kitool.data]
      });
    }
  });

  return result;

}, []).map((item, i, arr) => {
  
  /* Second phase of processing here to pad the data arrays with 0 values
  if needed */
  for (let i = item.data.length; i < arr.length; i++) {
    item.data.push(0);
  }
  return item;
});

console.log('result1:', result1);
console.log('result2:', result2);
```